# How to add possible divisor numbers?

Tags: r

How do I retrieve maximum sum of possible divisors numbers

I have a below function which will give possible divisors of number

**Code**

```
divisors <- function(x) {
  y <- seq_len(ceiling(x / 2))
  y[x %% y == 0]
}
```

**Example**
Divisors of 99 will give the below possible values.

```
divisors(99)
[1]  1  3  9 11 33
```

**My expected Logic :**

Go from last digit to first digit in the divisors value

1. The last number is 33, Here next immediate number divisible by 33 is 11 . So I selected 11 , now traversing from 11 the next immediate number divisible by 11 is 1. So selected 1. Now add all the numbers.
   **33 + 11 + 1  = 45**
2. Move to next number 11, Now next immediate number divisible by 11 is 1. So selected 1. Now add all the numbers.
   **11 + 1 = 12**
   Here immediate
3. Move to next number 9, Now next immediate number divisible by 11 is 1. So selected 1. Now add all the numbers.
   **9 + 3 + 1 = 13**
4. Move to next number 3,  Now next immediate number divisible by 3 is 1. So selected 1. Now add all the numbers.
   **3+1=4**

Now maximum among these is 45.

Now I am struggling to write this logic in R . Help / Advice much appreciated.

Note : Prime numbers can be ignored.

Comment: How is 11 divisible by 33? Read your first point. I don't get it. Also 3rd point is illogical

Comment: @Onyambu I guess OP meant 11 as a divisor of 33.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## update

For large integers, e.g., the maximum integer `.Machine$integer.max` (prime number), you can run the code below (note that I modified functions `divisors` and `f` a bit)

```
divisors <- function(x) {
    y <- seq(x / 2)
    y[as.integer(x) %% y == 0]
}

f <- function(y) {
    if (length(y) <= 2) {
        return(as.integer(sum(y)))
    }
    l <- length(y)
    h <- y[l]
    yy <- y[-l]
    h + f(yy[h %% yy == 0])
}
```

and you will see

```
> n <- .Machine$integer.max - 1

> x <- divisors(n)

> max(sapply(length(x):2, function(k) f(head(x, k))))
[1] 1569603656
```

---

You can define a recursive function `f` that gives successive divisors

```
f <- function(y) {
    if (length(y) == 1) {
        return(y)
    }
    h <- y[length(y)]
    yy <- y[-length(y)]
    c(f(yy[h %% yy == 0]), h)
}
```

and you will see all possible successive divisor tuples

```
> sapply(rev(seq_along(x)), function(k) f(head(x, k)))
[[1]]
[1]  1 11 33

[[2]]
[1]  1 11

[[3]]
[1] 1 3 9

[[4]]
[1] 1 3

[[5]]
[1] 1
```

Then, we apply `f` within `sapply` like below

```
> max(sapply(rev(seq_along(x)), function(k) sum(f(head(x, k)))))
[1] 45
```

which gives the desired output.

Comment: Very nice and concise dear Thomas.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR Thank you. Yours is excellent, upvoted already.

Comment: Thank you very much, not as good as yours, as you have clearly much more experience than me. However I'm happy I could get the desired output and also put some idea into practice.

Comment: any idea how the code which I mentioned works for big numbers like 100000000000 ? Note: I cant use any external package.

Comment: @ChennaiCheetah Do you have any runtime constraint for running with that big number?

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding I am getting this  Error: cannot allocate vector of size 74.5 Gb. Unfortunately  My coding  Env is limted to 512 Mb. I believe this error generates at divisor function which I posted. You have any thoughts on this to be handled in a better way.

Comment: @ChennaiCheetah Did you try my updated answer?

Comment: I tired . I am getting Error: cannot allocate vector of size 4.0 Gb .  n <- .Machine$integer.max - 1   gives me 2147483646

Comment: @ChennaiCheetah You cannot input an integer larger than `.Machine$integer.max`, otherwise you will encounter error. However, I cannot track what happened on your machine, since debugging may be needed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234381/discussion-between-chennai-cheetah-and-thomasiscoding).

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the following solution. It may sound a little bit complicated and of course there is always an easier, more efficient solution. However, I thought this could be useful to you. I will take it from your `divisors` output:

```
> x
[1]  1  3  9 11 33

# First I created a list whose first element is our original x and from then on
# I subset the first element till the last element of the list

lst <- lapply(0:(length(x)-1), function(a) x[1:(length(x)-a)])

> lst 
[[1]]
[1]  1  3  9 11 33

[[2]]
[1]  1  3  9 11

[[3]]
[1] 1 3 9

[[4]]
[1] 1 3

[[5]]
[1] 1
```

Then I wrote a custom function in order to implement your conditions and gather your desired output. For this purpose I created a **function factory** which in fact is a function that creates a function:

- As you might have noticed the outermost function does not take any argument. It only sets up an empty vector `out` to save our desired elements in. It is created in the execution environment of the outermost function to shield it from any changes that might affect it in the global environment
- The inner function is the one that takes our vector `x` so in general we call the whole setup like `fnf()(x)`. First element of of our `out` vector is in fact the first element of the original `x`(33). Then I found all divisors of the first element whose quotient were `0`. After I fount them I took the second element (11) as the first one was (33) and stored it in our `out` vector. Then I modified the original `x` vector and omitted the `max` value (33) and repeated the same process
- Since we were going to repeat the process over again, I thought this might be a good case to use **recursion**. Recursion is a programming technique that a function actually calls itself from its body or from inside itself. As you might have noticed I used `fn` inside the function to repeat the process again but each time with one fewer value
  This may sound a bit complicated but I believed there may be some good points for you to pick up for future exploration, since I found them very useful, hoped that's the case for you too.

```
fnf <- function() {
  out <- c()
  
  fn <- function(x) {
    out <<- c(out, x[1])
    z <- x[out[length(out)]%%x == 0]
    
    if(length(z) >= 2) {
      out[length(out) + 1] <<- z[2]
    } else {
      return(out)
    }
    x <- x[!duplicated(x)][which(x[!duplicated(x)] == z[2]):length(x[!duplicated(x)])]
    fn(x)
    
    out[!duplicated(out)]
  }
}

# The result of applying the custom function on `lst` would result in your
# divisor values
lapply(lst, function(x) fnf()(sort(x, decreasing = TRUE)))

[[1]]
[1] 33 11  1

[[2]]
[1] 11  1

[[3]]
[1] 9 3 1

[[4]]
[1] 3 1

[[5]]
[1] 1
```

In the end we sum each element and extract the `max` value

```
Reduce(max, lapply(lst, function(x) sum(fnf()(sort(x, decreasing = TRUE)))))
[1] 45
```

**Test**ing a very large integer number, I used dear @ThomasIsCoding's modified `divisors` function:

```
divisors <- function(x) {
    y <- seq(x / 2)
    y[as.integer(x) %% y == 0]
}

x <- divisors(.Machine$integer.max - 1)

lst <- lapply(0:(length(x)-1), function(a) x[1:(length(x)-a)])
Reduce(max, lapply(lst, function(x) sum(fnf()(sort(x, decreasing = TRUE)))))

[1] 1569603656
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to recurse. If I understand correctly, this should do what you want:

```
fact <- function(x) {
  x <- as.integer(x)
  div <- seq_len(abs(x)/2)
  factors <- div[x %% div == 0L]
  return(factors)
}

maxfact <- function(x) {
  factors <- fact(x)
  
  if (length(factors) < 3L) {
    return(sum(factors))
  } else {
    return(max(factors + mapply(maxfact, factors)))
  }
}

maxfact(99)
[1] 45
```